# Select records where ID is in the other table and status = 1

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to get all the records where table1.user is in table2.userid and table2.country = 8 and table2.status = 1

This is the sample data in my database

table1

```
id  user
--  ----
1    12
2    23
3    34
4    32
5    85
6    38
```

table2

```
id  userid  country_id  status
--  ----      -----      ----
1    12         5         1
2    12         8         1
3    85         8         1 
4    38         8         0         
5    38         7         1
6    23         8         1
7    23         4         1
```

in this case I should only get the id #3 in table2

Comment: And your attempt at this query is...?

Answer (score 3):

Inner join will do the job taking only record with match in the two tables.

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 on t1.user = t2.userid
WHERE t2.country=8 and t2.status=1
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work, yes it gets the records but the id #2 in table2 is also included. what I need to get is the id #3 in table2. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You mean

"get all the records where table1.user is in table2.userid
    ***with*** table2.country = 8 and table2.status = 1 ?"

If so, then:

```
Select * from table1 t1
Where Exists(Select * from table2
             Where userId = t1.user
                and country  = 8
                and status = 1)
```

Comment: `INNER JOIN` is the far-more natural way to solve this. See Adam Boileau's answer.

Comment: Although is opinion, I disagree, semantically, using `Exists` is closer to how problem would be stated in natural language, and is therefore clearer and more understandable. "*Where table1.user is in table2 ...*" the words "is IN" clearly translate to `exists`.  perhaps, rather than saying join is far more *natural* way .... @nasukkin should have said a "far more *geeky* way ... "

Comment: In general I try to stick to the pattern of using joins to "get" data from other tables to include it in my desired output resultset, When I want to filter or restrict the resultset based on the existence of a corresponding row or record in a table (either the base table or another related table), although a join will often work just fine,  I use an Exists subquery in the Where  clause. The way I look at it, Predicates that filter the result belong in the Where clause, that's where other filtering predicates go. Keeping them together simplifies reading/understanding the entire SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

Well to accomplish that is quite simple, you just need to make use of an inner join. An SQL JOIN clause is used to combine rows from two or more tables, based on a common field between them.

In your case, the INNER JOIN will return all rows from table2 where the join condition is met.

For a more detailed explanation and examples just visit this link: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

based on your response to Adam's approach " 
I tried this but it didn't work, yes it gets the records but the id #2 in table2 is also included. what I need to get is the id #3 in table2. Thanks :) ". I changed my SQL query to:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  table1
INNER JOIN
 table2
ON
table1.user = table2.userid
WHERE
table2.userid = 85
```

I assumed you only want the data of that particular userid in table2